# Technique to solve 2 x 2 block Toeplitz system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, least-squares, regression-analysis

I want to know how to solve this system of equations:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
R_{N} &-Q_{NM} \\
-Q_{NM}^T & P_M
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_N \\
b_M
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\epsilon^2\\ -\\
0 \\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The matrix is a 2 x 2 block matrix. $R_N$, $Q_{NM}$, $P_M$ are Toeplitz matrices. $N$ and $M$ represent the size of the dimensions of the matrices.

The solution will give vectors $a_N$ and $b_N$ and an error $\epsilon^2$.

What technique(s) can be used to solve this system? I don't understand the error term. The system also seems to be homogeneous which is also confusing me.

The equations are attempting to solve a weighted least squares problem. I don't know if I provided enough information, am happy to supply more, I just don't know what information may be most useful for someone to help me.

Comment: What is the dash in your 2nd column vector representing?

Comment: I'm not sure. It's from a research paper and the notation isn't familiar to me. I think it's implying that there is a small error in the system of equations as they are based on a mean least squares (possibly ARX) model. I am starting to think a singular value decomposition to find the null space of the matrix will be the right tool for the job, however, the paper implies that something much more efficient can be done based on the fact it's a 2x2 block Toeplitz.